# How to build a NN for classifying custom timeseries data?

Tags: python, neural-network, classification, keras

I'm trying to learn a little bit of machine learning and it occurred to me that my own household produces a lot of interesting data. Specifically, the ModBus-enabled digital power meter installed a few years ago, does. I've done quite a bit of professional work manually producing ground truth for an OCR system, but I've never done any programming in this space. I do know Python, but no NumPy or anything like it.

My question is threefold:

1. Are my assumptions thus far valid? (Especially about being able to "label" or "tag" the data as shown below...)
2. Is "[Timeseries Classification](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_classification_from_scratch/)" the thing I want to be doing (and is Keras the right tool for this project or is there a more suitable one)?
3. And then, most importantly: **How do the training data have to be treated to be able to train on them and then have unknown data classified or "tagged" like the GT?**

From what I believe to already understand about neural networks, the *meaning* of the input or output data does not matter much, just the way it's structured. Here's a short sample (incomplete, but all columns are numbers):

| timestamp | powerl1 | powerl2 | powerl3 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1688379471 | 49.79 | 0 | 120.98 |  |
| 1688379472 | 51.29 | 0 | 134.26 |  |
| 1688379473 | 50.32 | 0 | 0 |  |
| 1688379474 | 3282.83 | 3843.32 | 3694.20 |  |

My goal is to train a neural network to be able to recognize which devices are currently running. I know that it's possible to infer this knowledge from the data I have available because there's prior work (most notably [nilmtk](https://github.com/nilmtk/nilmtk), who seem to be trying to solve the problem with a much wider scope than just a single household, but also Adrien Petralia, a PhD student at Électricité de France; see [this](https://github.com/adrienpetralia/ApplianceDetectionBenchmark) and [this](https://github.com/adrienpetralia/TransApp) GitHub repo as well as  [this](https://doi.org/10.1145/3575813.3595198) paper).

For the above samples, to turn them into GT to be used for training, my idea is to add another column to them like so:

| ... | devices_running |
| --- | --- |
|  | aquarium_lights, gaming_PC |
|  | aquarium_lights, gaming_PC |
|  | aquarium_lights |
|  | aquarium_lights, flow_type_heater |

(So perhaps someone was using the gaming PC, then switched it off and began taking a shower. All the while, the aquarium lights were on.)

From the Keras tutorial linked to above, I understand I need to:

- *read the data* in (I know how to do this)
- *standardize* them (**does that mean evenly spaced periods of time?** Can I just use the code from the tutorial for that?)
- *build a model* (in this step, **what will be different with my data** as compared to the tutorial?)
- *train* the model (that part seems like it'll always be the same once you have a model)

I realize this question may not be specific enough to the StackExchange format. Please let me know in the comments if I can do anything to improve it.